# Displaying my 2D array code

Tags: java

Requirements:

1.How to display the stored data for each individual month without having to copy and paste code several times for the DisplayMonthData() method?

2.Is my code for summing up all the values for each month correct in DisplayMonthData()?

Thanks in advance.

```
      static void MonthData()
  {            
    try{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter item "+(i+1)+" <Press ENTER to exit> : ");
    monthItems[m][i] = input.next();
        if (monthItems[m][i].length() == 0){
            return;
        } else {
        System.out.print("Enter amount : $");
        amount[m][i] = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("");
        }   
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("");
    }   
    }
  static void DisplayMonthData()
  {
    if(months[m]=="Jan"){
    for(int row=1;row<amount.length;row++){
        for(int column=0;column<amount[row].length;column++){
            //janItems[]+=monthItems[1][0];
            if(amount[row][column]!=0){
             System.out.println(monthItems[row][column]+"\t$"+fmt.format(amount[row][column]));
            }else{}
        }
    }
        sum[L]+=amount[1][0];
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total amount spent for the month of January is $"+fmt.format(sum[L]));
        L++;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Please use a descriptive title instead of "Anyone can help?".

Comment: Why don't you write some test cases to find it out yourself?

Comment: I did all that but I find myself copying the code(in this case 12 times for no. of months)

Comment: Still any advice available for me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a parameter to take the month in the DisplayMonthData method. (Also make it start with a lower case letter per Java convention).
2. Define correct.  (Also use `.equals` for comparison of objects like Strings instead of `==`)

Comment: I'm absolutely a novice in Java which is to say I haven't the slightest idea what you're saying

Comment: Here is a hint instead of `void DisplayMonthData()` do this `void displayMonthData(String month)`